# transparent color in javascript D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

EDIT: I have a SVG graph produced with d3.js. The filled area of the graph is coloured by CSS rules. I would like the areas to be semi-transparent so that you can see data obscured by the foremost graph area.

Original:

Is there anyway to make the color of this graph transparent? http://jsfiddle.net/skys331/QBDGB/22/
I want to be able to see behind the green data.

Thanks

Comment: `fill: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);`? In any case, please make your questions stand-alone, i.e. include relevant code and the things you've tried or considered to fix your issue.

Comment: I think those who voted for closing this question demonstrated complete ignorance, or didn't even bother clicking the link in the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. You can use `transparent` for the fill, like so:

```
.line1 {
  fill: transparent;
  ...
}
```

You can alternatively set the opacity of the `.line1` element:

```
.line1 {
    fill: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Or set the fill to us `rgba` (RGB color with an alpha component):

```
.line1 {
    fill: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: There's also SVG attrs `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity`

Answer (score 4):

Add Opacity to the green:

```
.line1 {
  fill: green;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  opacity:0.5;

}
```

Edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/23/